# Vectorizing triple for loop in Python/Numpy with different array shapes

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, vectorization

I am new in Python/Numpy and is trying to improve my triple for loop into a more efficient calculation, but can't quiet figure out how to do it.

The calculations is carried out on a grid of the size (25,35) and the shapes of arrays is:

```
 A = (8760,25,35)
 B = (12,25,35)
```

The first dimensions in A corresponds to the number hours in a year (~8760), and the first dimension in B is the number of months(12). I want to use the values in B[0,:,:] for the first month, and B[1,:,:] for the second etc.

So far I created, in a very unrefined way, a index array filled with 1,1,1...,2,2,2...,12 to extract the values from B. My code with some random numbers

```
    N,M = (25, 35)
    A = np.random.rand(8760,N,M)
    B = np.random.rand(12,N,M)
    q = len(A)/12
    index = np.hstack((np.full((1,q),1),np.full((1,q),2),np.full((1,q),3),np.full((1,q),4),np.full((1,q),5),np.full((1,q),6),np.full((1,q),7),np.full((1,q),8),np.full((1,q),9),np.full((1,q),10),np.full((1,q),11),np.full((1,q),12)))-1
    results = np.zeros((len(A),N,M))

    for t in xrange(len(A)):
        for i in xrange(N):
            for j in xrange(M):
                results[t][i][j] = some_function(A[t][i][j], B[index[(0,t)]][i][j],H = 80.)


    def some_function(A,B,H = 80.0):
        results = A*np.log(H/B)/np.log(10./B)
        return results
```

How can increase the speed of this calculation?

Comment: Can you share details about `some_function`? Because for real vectorization, that function being *buried deep* inside the nested loops has to *come out* of the loops and that would depend on its implementation.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the function! I appreciate your help!

Comment: `index` being a 1D array would throw error at `index[(0,t)][i][j]`, because `index[(0,t)]` would be a scalar.

Comment: I think your code needs few changes : 1) `index` has to be subtracted by `1`.  2) Initalization of results be changed to `results = np.zeros((len(A),N,M))`. 3) `B[index[(0,t)][i][j]]` be changed to `B[index[(0,t)]][i][j]`.

Comment: Thank for the remarks, I have updated the code. How would you continue from here to vectorize the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy suports [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) that allows elementwise operations to be performed across different shaped arrays in a highly optimized manner. In your case, you have the number of rows and columns in `A` and `B` the same. But, at the first dimension, the number of elements are different across these two arrays. Looking at the implementation, it seems `B` 's first dimension elements are repeated per `q` number until we go over to the next element in it's first dimension. This coincides with the fact that the number of elements in first dimension of `B` is `q` times the number of elements in first dimension of `A`.

Now, going back to `broadcasting`, the solution would be to *split* the first dimension of `A` to have a 4D array, such that we have the number of elements in the first dimension of this reshaped 4D array matching up with the number of elements in B's first dimension. Next up, `reshape` `B` to a 4D array as well by creating singleton dimension (dimension with no elements) at the second dimension with `B[:,None,:,:]`. Then, NumPy would use broadcasting magic and perform broadcasted elementwise multiplications, as that's what we are doing in our `some_function`.

Here's the vectorized implementation using [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) capability -

```
H = 80.0
M,N,R = B.shape
B4D = B[:,None,:,:]
out = ((A.reshape(M,-1,N,R)*np.log(H/B4D))/np.log(10./B4D)).reshape(-1,N,R)
```

Runtime tests and output verification -

```
In [50]: N,M = (25, 35)
    ...: A = np.random.rand(8760,N,M)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(12,N,M)
    ...: H = 80.0
    ...: 

In [51]: def some_function(A,B,H = 80.0):
    ...:     return A*np.log(H/B)/np.log(10./B)
    ...: 

In [52]: def org_app(A,B,H):
    ...:    q = len(A)/len(B)
    ...:    index = np.repeat(np.arange(len(B))[:,None],q,axis=1).ravel()[None,:] # Simpler
    ...:    results = np.zeros((len(A),N,M))
    ...:    for t in xrange(len(A)):
    ...:        for i in xrange(N):
    ...:            for j in xrange(M):
    ...:                results[t][i][j] = some_function(A[t][i][j], B[index[(0,t)]][i][j])
    ...:    return results
    ...: 

In [53]: def vectorized_app(A,B,H):
    ...:    M,N,R = B.shape
    ...:    B4D = B[:,None,:,:]
    ...:    return ((A.reshape(M,-1,N,R)*np.log(H/B4D))/np.log(10./B4D)).reshape(-1,N,R)
    ...: 

In [54]: np.allclose(org_app(A,B,H), vectorized_app(A,B,H))
Out[54]: True

In [55]: %timeit org_app(A,B,H)
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 32s per loop

In [56]: %timeit vectorized_app(A,B,H)
10 loops, best of 3: 217 ms per loop
```